# Java: Casting a Generic Class Given a Class Object

Tags: java, casting

Is it at all possible to cast a generic class's type to a given Class object in java? Something like this:

```
public ModelBin<?> getModelBin(Class type) {
    return (ModelBin<type>) entities.get(type);
}
```

The compiler tells me that it can't resolve type to a type. I know I could just do this,

```
public ModelBin<?> getModelBin(Class type) {
    return entities.get(type);
}
```

and it would work but then I would have to cast each model out of the model bin later on in the program - which is more work.

---

I did some more reading and ended up with this:

```
public <T> ModelBin<T> getModelBin(Class<T> type) {
    return (ModelBin<T>) entities.get(type);
}
```

Would this have the funciton return a `ModelBin<type>` object?

Comment: entities is a `HashMap<Class, ModelBin<?>>`

Comment: There isn't any type-safe solution. You'll have to ensure the map can only contain valid mappings. Also, use `Class<?>` instead of the raw `Class`.

Comment: With type erasure this is a lot more difficult, as at runtime you may not be able to be sure that the type is an instance of ModelBin<T> | https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: The purpose of this structure is to sort various entities to be rendered on screen via various shader - depending on Class<T> type - so I "know" what will be stored in the Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public <T> ModelBin<T> getModelBin(Class<T> type) {
    return (ModelBin<T>) entities.get(type);
}
```

This is the generally-accepted way to do this in a type-safe manner.

```
final ModelBin<String> myStrBin = getModelBin(String.class);
```

will compile correctly.

> Would this have the function return a ModelBin object?

This will look correct to the compiler, yes. At runtime, the returned `ModelBin` won't have a type (due to erasure), but that's just the way that Java is designed.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible and the reason is [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). In your code it decides using runtime values what class to cast to, an due to Type Erasure type parameters are not available at that time (only compilation).

Another [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html) of Type Erasure